# time.time vs. timeit.timeit

Tags: python, performance, time, python-3.x

Sometimes, I like to time how long it takes parts of my code to run.  I've checked a lot of online sites and have seen, at large, two main ways to do this.  One is using `time.time` and the other is using `timeit.timeit`.

So, I wrote a very simple script to compare the two:

```
from timeit import timeit
from time import time
start = time()
for i in range(100): print('ABC')
print(time()-start, timeit("for i in range(100): print('ABC')", number=1))
```

Basically, it times how long it takes to print "ABC" 100 times in a for-loop.  The number on the left is the results for `time.time` and the number on the right is for `timeit.timeit`:

```
# First run
0.0 0.012654680972022981
# Second run
0.031000137329101562 0.012747430190149865
# Another run
0.0 0.011262325239660349
# Another run
0.016000032424926758 0.012740166697164025
# Another run
0.016000032424926758 0.0440628627381413
```

As you can see, sometimes, time.time is faster and sometimes it's slower.  Which is the better way (more accurate)?

Comment: `timeit` is the better choice for timing chunks of code. It uses `time.time()` (`time.clock()` for Windows) and disables the garbage collector. Also, one trial isn't really enough.

Comment: @Blender: `timeit` uses `time.perf_counter` in Python 3.3+

Answer (score 100, accepted):

`timeit` is more accurate, for three reasons:

- it repeats the tests many times to eliminate the influence of other tasks on your machine, such as disk flushing and OS scheduling.
- it disables the garbage collector to prevent that process from skewing the results by scheduling a collection run at an inopportune moment.
- it picks the most accurate timer for your OS, `time.time` or `time.clock` in Python 2 and [`time.perf_counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter) on Python 3. See [`timeit.default_timer`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.default_timer).

Comment: If you explicitly do those three things you get results as accurate as timeit? My use case is running many tests with different inputs, so figure it might be easier to dispense with timeit.

Comment: @Annan: Why reinvent this wheel? I'm sure that whatever usecase you can come up with, provided you understand what it means to run something repeatedly, can be supplied for by `timeit`. There are a few smaller minor tricks `timeit` uses (such as using `itertools.repeat(None, repetitioncount)` for a low-friction repetition range) that you'd have to replicate too if you want to be as 'accurate' as `timeit` gets.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I'm wondering if `%timeit` is the built-in magic command for `timeit`, how about `%time`. Is `%time` the same when we use  `time.clock()` (put 2 time.clock at the beginning and the end of the code and calculate the time difference). I've read here but not enough info https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html . Thanks

Comment: @Catbuilts: `%time` doesn't do any repetition. It's  a straightforward 'run once, report time differences' operation.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Sorry if my question was not clear, I understand `%time` doesn't do repetition, while `%timeit` does. My question was: Is `%time` a shortcut (built-in magic command) to call `time.clock()` ? From the link ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html, it said that `%timeit` is Time execution of a Python statement using the `timeit` module, but it didn't tell anything about `%time`. I wonder where `%time` comes from, what exactly runs under the hood. Thanks

Comment: @Catbuilts: it's a [bit more complicated than that](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/0fbad83245f474c4dd7a1b1fbe7f2ea79e005653/IPython/core/magics/execution.py#L1226-L1244), but not much.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thank you for the link. It uses `time.time()` to calculate `wall time`.

Comment: But `%% timeit` uses first statement as the 'set up code'. What the hell that is supposed to mean?

Comment: @amsquareb: The setup block is run *once*, letting you create the right objects (context) for the repeated tests.

Comment: I'm not convinced that disabling the garbage collector always makes it more accurate. See [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63757763/13008439) where I think the garbage collection is responsible for most of the time and it is caused by the measured code so it shouldn't be ignored.

Comment: @superbrain interesting; adding `gc.disable()` and `gc.enable()` around your second timed test indeed eliminates the difference. This requires further investigation as there are no circular references there for the gc to bother with. You appear to have hit a rare edge case.

Answer (score 6):

At any given time, the Central Processing Unit (CPU) is used and shared by many processes. Measurements taken using [`time.time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time) are relative to what we call *wall clock*. This means that the results are dependent to the other processes that were running at the time the test was executed. Therefore, in many cases the results produced by [`time.time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time) are not as accurate as possible.

More reliable results can be generated using [`time.clock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.clock) for Python 2.x and  [`time.process_time()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.process_time) or [`time.perf_counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter) for Python 3.X, that measures the CPU cycles used during the execution of the code but even this method as it heavily relies on the specific machine you are executing the tests. For example, the results might hugely differ if the tests are executed on different machines (even though the algorithm and input data are both exactly the same)

---

[`timeit.timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit) is a an advanced library that is more accurate and reliable compared to [`time.time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time) and [`time.clock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.clock) as it takes into account the factors that pose the variance among the code executions and trials, by simply repeating the execution of tests in order to produce more reliable and accurate results.+