# Why is a Python dict comprehension ignoring the first element in the dict?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, key-value, dictionary-comprehension

I'm trying to convert to `floats` the `string` values (which should have been represented as float originally) in the following dict:

```
{'a': '1.3', 'b': '4'}
```

If I try a dict comprehension:

```
{k:float(v) for v in d.values()}
```

I end up with just the second item in the dict:

```
In [191]: {k:float(v) for v in d.values()}
Out[191]: {'b': 4.0}
```

Why is this?

Comment: `{k:float(v) for v in d.values()}` in this expression were is your `k` is coming from ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `d.items()` and also you need to refer key,value separately through variables. Here `k` refers the key and `v` refers the value.

```
{k:float(v) for k,v in d.items()}
```

Example:

```
>>> d = {'a': '1.3', 'b': '4'}
>>> {k:float(v) for k,v in d.items()}
{'a': 1.3, 'b': 4.0}
```

Answer (score 6):

The `k` value is not changed for every `v` value, change your code to below:

```
{k:float(v) for k, v in d.items()}
```

Answer (score 3):

Python dictionaries [iteritems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24194586/3270800) would be more appropriate solution.

```
{k:float(v) for k, v in d.iteritems()}
```

Also read [dict.items() vs dict.iteritems()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458437/what-is-the-difference-between-dict-items-and-dict-iteritems)

Answer (score 3):

Your `k` variable contains `'b'` for some reason. Therefore your expression

```
{k:float(v) for v in d.values()}
```

is actually

```
{'b': float(v) for v in d.values()}
```

so the result is:

```
{'b': 4.0}
```