# Tensorflow operation time fluctuations

Tags: python, tensorflow, time

I want to measure the time it takes my session to run inference operations.
I measured it using `time` like so

```
start = time.clock()
sess.run([ops['pred']], feed_dict=feed_dict)
end = time.clock()
elapsed_time_batch = end-start
```

I do this multiple times on the same dataset and average. 
The problem is - I get very different average time measurements ( 1.7ms vs 1.2 ms ). Even though its "just" 0.5ms difference its a big relative difference ( 0.5 vs 1.7 is about 30%).

I tried setting some GPU options for the session like so :

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.95
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = False
config.allow_soft_placement = True
config.log_device_placement = False
if limit_gpu:
        gpu_idx = str(gpu_idx)
        os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = gpu_idx
else:
        os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0, 1"
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
```

But, this didn't solve it. What can be the cause of this change and how can I stabilize it to get a more reliable time read.

I am running on a linux server with 4 GPUS ( for this test I limited to 1 GPU - a Titan Xp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured it out so I am posting the answer here for others who may encounter this in the future.

It seems that the function `time.clock()` is not the right choice here (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579357/time-time-vs-timeit-timeit) answer for detail).

The solution is to use the `timeit.timer()` function:

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
start = timer()
sess.run([ops['pred']], feed_dict=feed_dict)
end = timer()
elapsed_time_batch = end-start
```