# Is there a function to see how long a script takes to run?

Tags: python

I have a python script than can sort files and i want to know how long it takes to run.

i searched for a module that's names time but it didnt work and it asked me to put a real time.

Comment: Try the `timeit` module in the standard library

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I measure elapsed time in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370801/how-do-i-measure-elapsed-time-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate execution time like that:

```
import time

start_time = time.time()

# your script here

end_time = time.time()
execution_time = end_time - start_time

print("Execution time:", execution_time, "seconds")
```

Comment: For rough timing, `time` will work, but for accurate performance measurement, then the `timeit` module is preferred (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17579466/20121320))

Comment: thanks, both of ur solutions worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use `time.perf_counter()` if we are talking about timing code:

```py
from time import perf_counter

# Get the start 'time'
t1 = perf_counter()

# Some complex time-consuming function
for i in range(10**9):
    pass

# Get the end 'time'
t2 = perf_counter()

# Now you subtract the start time from the end time and you have your elapsed time:
print("Elapsed time:",t2-t1)
```

Check the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter

Comment: Ty for the documentation, didn't think to check that